# Accessing MySQL database from iPhone directly

Tags: iphone, mysql

I am trying to connect my iPhone aap directly to the MySQL database. I did a lot of reading, and I found that by using MCPkit we can access the database. Now I also found that the mcpkit is not supported in iPhone, while it runs in simulator.

I know the other alternative is web services, but I have to directly connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no way out of using MySQL directly, then you might consider to have a look at Sequel Pro which picked up where CocoaMySQL left. It appears to be actively maintained whereas MCPKit haven't released any updates in a couple of years.

I can't say whether Sequel Pro will allow you to build for the iPhone, but my guess is that it will have a higher chance of success than MCPKit.

You can grab a copy of Sequel Pro including source code (GPL) from [the official website](https://sequelpro.com/download).